# Error when running ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b “” -LLL “+”

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am new to `LDAP` and `OpenLDAP`

When running very basic `ldapsearch`

```
ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b “” -LLL “+”
```

It returns

```
ldapsearch: invalid option -- 'H'
```

in CentOS 7

but if I run

```
sudo ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b “” -LLL “+”
```

the `invalid option` error is gone but then it returns

```
Invalid DN syntax (34)
Additional information: invalid DN
```

I think it looks like I messed up some of the configuration, all I did was following instruction from this [tutorial](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/step-step-openldap-server-configuration-centos-7-rhel-7.html)

Please let me know any extra information i should provide here and how can I resolve the problem. I am really newbie in `(Open)LDAP`.

## UPDATE

Content of `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/db.ldif`

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=myname,dc=local

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=ldapadm,dc=myname,dc=local

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}123123123123123123123
```

Comment: It seems you are using left/right double quotation mark to quote your arguments but it's not supported by unix shell quoting mechanism, try using simple or double quotes :   

`sudo ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b '' -LLL '+'`

Comment: @EricLavault awesome, really appreciate your comments and that's exactly the problem! Please make your comment as an answer so I will close this thread. Thanks again !

Comment: use -h hostname instead, it always works (without ldap:// and a lowercase h)

Comment: Note the `-h` option is deprecated in favor of `-H`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left/right double quotation mark `“ ”` are not supported by unix shell quoting mechanism, you have to use simple or double quotes `'' or ""` to enclose your arguments.

This should work :

```
sudo ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -s base -b '' -LLL '+'
```

See also the [difference between single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).